# How to sort a textfile based on the string value of the last column using python?

Tags: python, sorting, integer, multiple-columns

I have an issue sorting a large text file.
The text file looks like this:

```
word, two words, 15, 988, anotherword, 99
also some words, nope, 20, 122, characters, 39
text, words words, 10, 300, more words, 9
```

The end of each line has a newline character (\n).

I would like to sort this file descending, based on the integer in the last column.

I used the following code I found here on stackoverflow:

```
from operator import itemgetter

with open ('sourcefile.txt') as fin:
lines = [line.split(',') for line in fin]
lines.sort(key=itemgetter(5),reverse=True)
with open('sortedfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for el in lines:
        fout.write('{0}\n'.format(','.join(el)))
```

The problem I'm getting with this solution is that the script is sorting alphabetically. Like so:

```
word, two words, 15, 988, anotherword, 99
text, words words, 10, 300, more words, 9
also some words, nope, 20, 122, characters, 39
```

What could be a practical solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code with some optimizations:

```py
with open ('sourcefile.txt') as fin, open('sortedfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
    lines_and_numbers = [(line, int(line.rsplit(',', 1)[1])) for line in fin]
    for el in sorted(lines_and_numbers, key=lambda l:l[1], reverse=True):
        fout.write(el[0])
```

I create a list `lines_and_numbers` that consists of tuples containing the original line as element 0 and the integer number from each line's last column as element 1.

Then I iterate over this list sorted by element 1 of each tuple.

That way you don't have to join each split line together again and you don't need to append another line break, as the old one is still present.

I also replaced that imported function with a simple lambda expression.

Comment: This worked like a charm. It took me a while to understand what you did, but I think I do now! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidDeSmedt Instead of writing "Thank you" comments, please accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick symbol on the left of it. You can learn more in the [help] or on the small [tour] page about how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting strings, so they will be sorted alphabetically. If you want to sort numerically, make sure you sort integers. To do this, make sure that the sixth element in `lines` is actually an integer, by simply calling:

`lines[5] = int(lines[5])`

before you sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could first split the string with newline; then sort the list based on the the integer in the last column. `[::-1]` is to reverse the list, so that it's in descending order.

```
import re
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as fin, open('fout.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('\n'.join(sorted( fin.read().split('\n'), key=lambda x: int(re.findall('(\d+)', x)[-1]))[::-1]))
```

Output file content:

```
word, two words, 15, 988, anotherword, 99
also some words, nope, 20, 122, characters, 39
text, words words, 10, 300, more words, 9
```